# Terminate background execution

Tags: swift, multithreading

How it is possible to terminate Thread/Task/Operation/Work in Swift.

I know about method "cancel" that sets an indicator that operation should cancel as soon as possible. But wonder if it possible to force kill the background task.

For example to copy a file I invoke:
`FileManager.default.copyItem` This method doesn't support cancellation.

So my question is: is there a way in Swift or in Objective-C to force terminate background execution?

Comment: No, there's not. Terminating threads requires cooperation from the thread you're killing. It needs to check a flag periodically during it's time-consuming work and stop and clean up shop if it gets canceled. Otherwise you'd risk leaving things in an indeterminate state (memory leaks or worse)

Comment: Terminating file system operations by killing their threads would be especially fraught, since it could damage the file system. I don't know of any FileManager file copy operations that support cancellation. (There might be some - I'm just not aware of them.)